# How to pass Codeigniter controller array to view and use foreach function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't access codeigniter controller array values in the view. where did i miss.

**mymodel**

```
function get_data(){        
    $this->db->select('prod_id, content, details');
    $query = $this->db->get('tblesample');        
    return $query->result();   
}
```

**controller**

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('mymodel'); 
    $user_info = $this->mymodel->get_data();

    $this->load->view('inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('data_view', $user_info);        
}
```

**data_view**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <?php
        foreach ($user_info as $info) {
            echo $info->content;
        } 
    ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You be better off using associative array to pass on to the view:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('mymodel'); 
    $data = [
        'user_info' => $this->mymodel->get_data(),
    ];

    $this->load->view('inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('data_view', $data);        
}
```

And reference it like `$user_info` in your view.

Answer (score 3):

In controller change the code.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('mymodel'); 
    $data['user_info'] = $this->mymodel->get_data();

    $this->load->view('inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('data_view', $data);        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the array correctly to view . Pass your data like this

```
    public function index(){
    $this->load->model('mymodel'); 
    $user_info['user_info'] = $this->mymodel->get_data();
    $this->load->view('inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('data_view', $user_info);         
}
```